# Text is blacked out when taking a firefox screenshot running headless with xvfb

Tags: selenium, amazon-ec2, jenkins, xvfb

I have a jenkins setup on amazon ec2 and everything is running fine except for a tiny issue with Selenium. Every time I run the whole suite of tests (~30 min), Selenium gets stuck on a test. I've take a screenshot at that moment and it seems that there is an alert on the screen, but the alert text is all blacked out.

[image: xvfb on ec2, alert]

I've run xvfb, started selenium, then taken my screen capture with xwd and converted that image with imagemagick.

I've scoured the internet and have no clue.

Comment: You could use selenium to read the alert text. This obviously does not answer your question, but it would kill you curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Turns out that it's a font thing. I've run the steps indicated below and now I can read the text. It's still on a dark green background, but the text is readable.

On amazon ec2 ubuntu instance need to:

1) enable multiverse for apt-get

- Open `/etc/apt/sources.list` with any editor
- On ec2 it seems the multiverse isn't present so copied these lines into the file and saved

  - `deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid multiverse`
  - `deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid multiverse`
  - `deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates multiverse`
  - `deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates multiverse`

2) `sudo apt-get update`

3) `sudo apt-get -y install x-ttcidfont-conf cabextract ttf-mscorefonts-installer`

- this will bring up shell gui, use arrow down, tab, and enter to navigate
- accept EULA

4) `sudo dpkg-reconfigure x-ttcidfont-conf`
    - choose freetype fonts